# Speed up Lucene index building process

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, lucene

I'm working on [this class](http://pastebin.com/Rmy1GFhK) to build a couple of indexes (categories and entries) in Lucene for an old web app (Lucene 2.0, Java 6).

The thing is it takes too long to build the indexes: 10 minutes on Intel i3 for a 50 MB index containing 60000 entries and a 20 MB index containing 10000 categories.

I would like to speed up the process so I don't have to wait an eternity every time I add/edit an entry to have it indexed.

The entries/categories are read from a MySQL database using Hibernate and JDBC driver and, despite the SQL tables being properly indexed, at first I thought this was where the bottleneck was located (I'm performing 20000 MySQL queries in total**). But each query takes less than 1 milliseconds on average, so I guess that's not the case.

Before I set up and run a profiler which may just tell me what I already know, I would like to know if anybody has any straight forward suggestions on how to improve the index building performance... Perhaps a more recent version of Lucene or Java 7 would help? Or is it the [Analyzer](http://pastebin.com/Si8Yu1sn) I'm using?

** *(2 per category: the first to find sub-categories for a category and the second to find entries for a category)*

Comment: Why do you rebuild the whole index each time you add/edit? Why don't you just update the index?

Comment: I rebuild every hour or so, not on every update, but you may be right. I could switch to real time updates, I don't know why that wasn't implemented by the previous developer in the first place.

Comment: I've also been reading on scheduling incremental updates. They seem to fit what I need too, although a little more complex to implement: First I'd need to go through the whole index removing deleted entries/categories, then instead of creating a new index and add a doc for each entry/category I'd query the index first to check if a doc exists for that entry/category, and if it doesn't I'd append it to the index. But I don't know if this would be more efficient than rebuilding the whole index...

Comment: You can rebuild the whole index once per day, in case the add/update didn't work correctly, to make sure that it is updated. But i would of use a real-time update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of having the question closed (credit goes to @Joshua for his comments):

I set up the profiler. I was not wrong. Solution: schedule [parallel incremental updates](https://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ParallelIncrementalIndexing) + rebuilding the whole index periodically (once every 2-3 days was enough on this particular case).